# Avoid reloading Javascript after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html file with the following structure:

```
<div id="timer"></div>

<div id="top">

</div>
<button id="showBottom">Show Bottom</button>

<div id="bottom">

</div>
<button id="next">Next</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

Each time `Next` is clicked, the `Top` div gets new data from an AJAX call and the `Bottom` div is cleared.  When the `Show Bottom` is clicked, it also makes an AJAX call.

I have it set up such that when `Show Bottom` is clicked, the timer is started.

```
$('#timer').countdown({
        until: '+2m',
        format: 'MS',
        compact: true
    });
```

Upon clicking `Next`, the `timer` is destroyed and reset to 0:00.  But once I reach the next section and click `Show Bottom`, I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'countdown'`... the only way I can get it to work is if I include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

in the file that gets loaded in `Top`.  Basically reload those files each time.

Is there a way that I do not have to keep reloding these two files?

Comment: Those two files are being cached automatically, aren't they?

Comment: @Jack, are you calling $('#timer').countdown() inside the file that is loaded into the Top div?

Comment: It's would be helpful if you can add those loading files as well! and your js functions!